how to fill markers for certain groups geom_point
HCI Graph
I am trying to highlight a group of countries among others. In particular, I want to highlight countries that are important markets to the US in Africa, while fading the others into the background. I've tried using the alpha function in geom_point, which gives me what I want for the other countries, but I have not figured out a way to bring the countries labeled "U.S. Market" to the front.
Here is the code I've been using below:
ggplot(HC,aes(W.RGDP,WHCI,label=HC$`Country Name`))+geom_point(aes(fill=`Comparison 2`),size=8,pch=21,alpha=0.4)+
  labs(x="Real GDP Per Capita (log)",y="Human Capital Index")+
  ggtitle("Human Capital Index & GDP Per Capita", subtitle="SSA & World (by income group)")+
  stat_smooth(method="glm",se=TRUE,color="firebrick2")+geom_text(check_overlap=T,family="serif")+
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(HC$`Comparison 2`=="U.S. Market",paste0(HC$`Country Name`),""),family="serif"))+
  theme_stata(base_size = 14,base_family="serif")+scale_x_continuous(labels=dollar_format())+
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=7)))+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),legend.position=c(0.12,0.75),
        legend.background=element_rect(colour=NA,fill=NA),
        panel.border=element_rect(color="black",fill="NA"),
        plot.subtitle=element_text(face="italic",size=14))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#1F78B4","#A6CEE3","#33A02C","#B2DF8A","darksalmon","gold3"),
                    breaks=c("High income","Upper middle income","Lower middle income","Low income","Africa","U.S. Market"))

I've also attached a picture of the graph.
I was able to bring the text that I want to the front by using geom_text, but I can't figure out a way to do something similar with geom_point. I would love it if I could use an ifelse function like I did for the text.
I have tied subsetting the data, which has not worked...I keep getting an error about the aesthetics length.
structure(list(`Country Name` = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Belarus", 
"Belgium", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", 
"Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam"), `Comparison 2` = c("Low income", 
"Upper middle income", "U.S. Market", "U.S. Market", "High income", 
"Upper middle income", "Upper middle income", "High income", 
"High income", "Upper middle income", "High income", "Lower middle income", 
"Upper middle income", "High income", "Africa", "Lower middle income", 
"Upper middle income", "Africa", "Upper middle income", "High income"
), `HCI 2020` = c(0.400284141302109, 0.634250938892365, 0.534556448459625, 
0.362405389547348, 0.595703899860382, 0.602144718170166, 0.578998804092407, 
0.770239531993866, 0.746739745140076, 0.577767550945282, 0.652472019195557, 
0.46403643488884, 0.700078189373016, 0.76041966676712, 0.400290727615356, 
0.475297033786774, 0.57968407869339, 0.414028495550156, 0.551497936248779, 
0.626391351222992), `Real GDP Per Capita (3-year average) (log)` = c(2.63994355604787, 
3.68217708824842, 3.65453362326108, 3.38066789845535, 4.20466171351866, 
4.08791987813632, 3.66586025270983, 4.77398337179505, 4.65329694576918, 
3.72765661725707, 4.36960984791812, 3.22739691265819, 3.79971743950937, 
4.63045716032335, 3.08331073406556, 3.50531148290221, 3.77030705526165, 
3.79820120774174, 3.93248670657043, 4.47241060052674)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


The reprex code you provided to produce your chart is referencing variables (e.g. W.RGDP) that aren't present in the data you've shared.

Do you want to bring some specific points in the front ? (Subset your dataset, and make two geom_point() calls with different levels of alpha).  Or you just want to highlight them? A nice way would be to encode alpha as a aes() with a specific variable. That way, you can also express the income level as a color without mixing other information (US market, Africa) .
